# How can i rearrange this divs when responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please i want to rearrange this divs when it reaches col-sm-12 that the "two" will be on top of "one". Is there any way i can do it. Thanks. I would be very grateful. My code is below

```css
.one {
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.two {
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid blue
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `order` property with media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .one {
        order: 2;    
    }
    .two {
        order: 1;    
    }
}
```

```css
.one {
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  order: 2;
}

.two {
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  order: 1;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want it to swap when i resize the screen to col-sm-12 not at full screen

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-xs-2">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-xs-1">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want it to swap when i resize the screen to col-sm-12 not at full screen

Comment: I have edited my answer, I guess this would solve your issue now.